# Medical Term for Aylonit איילונית

Tags: medicine

Is there a modern medical term for an איילונית? Is this someone just lacking female hormones?

Comment: I bet Artscroll has something to say about this

Comment: I don't have time to read this but maybe [this medical halacha encyclopedia](https://www.medethics.org.il/article/%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%AA/) addresses it. A quick glance looks like it suggests [Turner syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turner_syndrome).

Comment: @robev Thank you, this is an amazing resource.

Comment: Is there some reason to think only one medical syndrome matches אילונית? Rather, an אילונית is whatever fits the descriptions in chazal including any medical conditions that qualify.

Comment: @DoubleAA would a request for a list of all known medical conditions which match the descriptions of Chazal be more suitable?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Androgen_insensitivity_syndrome

Comment: @kouty Isn't that a סריס or טומטום?

Comment: @DoubleAA Good point. But I guess that is the question I'm asking.